# How to disable depth of field?

Tags: pc, unravel

Without a doubt, Unravel is one of the most graphically impressive 2D platformers. Unfortunately the game uses prominent depth of field effect (with film grain) that blurs the background , it is only possible to switch between "high" and "low" in the settings:

[image: high]
*high*

[image: low]
*low (still noticeably blurred; enlarge the screenshot)*

Answer (score 1):

Reviewing this I can not see any options to reduce it beyond low.

I've freshly installed Unravel to see if it generates any additional config files where you could change something like 
`depth of field = 0`.

However this doesn't appear to be the case and it looks like high and low are your only two options.

Comment: I have checked too, all data files are encrypted.